# How can I return number of days AND hours before a certain datetime is reached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a daily deal application to learn Ruby on Rails.

I'd like to display for each deal how long until the deal is no longer available in days AND hours.

I am now using in my view:

```
Ends in : <%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(game.game_end_date) %>
```

If there are only a few hours left, it works well and returns for example "deal ends in 3 hours".

When there is still more than ONE day to go the method  returns "deal ends in about 2 days".
I would like to display something more precise in that case with the number of days AND hours. For example, it should return "deal ends in 2 days and 7 hours".

Is there a Rails method for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the gem [dotiw](https://github.com/radar/dotiw) that has more options than the classic `distance_of_time_in_words`:

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, game.game_end_date, false, :only => ["days", "hours"]) %>
```